# PPPD: Modem Hangup After PAP Authentication Success

Tags: raspberry-pi, ppp

I am trying to connect to the internet with SIM7600 module - https://www.waveshare.com/sim7600e-h-4g-hat.htm

Used following `chat` and `dial` files:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pppd call dial
abort on (BUSY)
abort on (NO ANSWER)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/ppp/chat
# 
# chat script 
# 
# 
        ABORT           'BUSY'
        ABORT           'NO ANSWER'
        ABORT           'NO CARRIER'
        ABORT           'NO DIALTONE'
        ABORT           '\nRINGING\r\n\r\nRINGING\r'
        SAY                     "modem init: press <ctrl>-C to disconnect\n"


        ''              '+++ATH'
#       OK              'ATZ'
#       OK              'ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0'
#       OK              'AT+IFC=0,0'
#       OK              'AT&W'
        SAY             "Before Connecting\n"

#       OK              'AT+CSOCKAUTH=,,"WAP@WAP",""'
        OK              'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","AIRTELWAP.ES"'
        SAY             "\n + defining PDP context\n"

#       OK              'ATD#777'
        OK              'ATD*99#'
        SAY             "Number Dialled\n"

#       OK              'AT+CGATT=1'
        SAY             "\n + attaching"
# simcom
#       OK              'AT+CIPSTART'
#       SAY             "\n + attaching to GPRS"

        SAY             "\n + requesting data connection"
#       CONNECT         ''
        CONNECT         \d\c
        SAY             "\n + connected"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/ppp/peers/dial
#
# pppd options
#
modem
debug
#logfile /var/ppplog 
nodetach 
/dev/ttyUSB2
115200
receive-all
#defaultroute
noipdefault
-chap
usepeerdns
#mtu 1500
-crtscts
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
lock
#nodeflate
noauth
novj
nobsdcomp
novjccomp
nopcomp
noaccomp
asyncmap 0
user "WAP@WAP"
password ""

#lcp-echo-failure 0
#lcp-echo-interval 0

# Chat scripts
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -s -f /etc/ppp/chat"
```

But modem hangup after authentication:

```
abort on (BUSY)
abort on (NO ANSWER)
abort on (NO CARRIER)
abort on (NO DIALTONE)
abort on (\nRINGING\r\n\r\nRINGING\r)
modem init: press <ctrl>-C to disconnect
send (+++ATH^M)
Before Connecting
expect (OK)
ATH^M^M
OK
 -- got it

send (AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","AIRTELWAP.ES"^M)

 + defining PDP context
expect (OK)
^M
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","AIRTELWAP.ES"^M^M
OK
 -- got it

send (ATD*99#^M)
Number Dialled

 + attaching
expect (CONNECT)ta connection
^M
ATD*99#^M^M
CONNECT
 -- got it

send (\d)

Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -s -f /etc/ppp/chat finished (pid 21132), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 5
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x6956f661>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x13 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd148b499> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x13 <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x6956f661>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x14 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd148b499>]
sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x14 <auth pap>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x15 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xd148b499>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x15 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xd148b499>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x6956f661]
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="WAP@WAP" password=<hidden>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x16 magic=0xd148b499]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xd148b499 69 56 f6 61]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
```

I have added `nodeflate` to `/etc/ppp/options` file to disable compression.

Does anyone have same issue with this modem?

Comment: This looks like APN conflict. Check your PDP context -> are you using default PDP context e.g. 1 or something else e.g. 3? I faced similar issues and it turned out that there were multiple APNs (default and non default) conflicting resulting in cell provider kicking out the connection (LCP terminated by peer).